# Incorrect representation of a scrollable list into a masonry-grid

Tags: css, google-chrome, masonry

I have a problem with an masonry-grid and a scrollable list inside this grid. Look at the screeshot:
[Screenshot with scroll problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPAIT.png)

The list-items protrude above and below the widget. This problem does not exist if the widget is at the top position (first column) of the grid. This problem exists only in Chrome and not in Firefox.

Here is an example of my masonry-grid:

```
.widgets {
  margin: 1em;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: block;
  column-gap: 2em;
  column-count: 3;
} 

.wigdet {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Does anybody have a similar problem or a solution for it?

Comment: Can you share your markup and a minimal, concrete, and verifiable example?

Comment: I found a workaround. The problem only exists if I use the material list items. If I use a div, the problem does not occur.